# Windows forms ReportViewer issue

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer

I am using Reportviewer in WIndows forms for the first time and had some strange issue. I have a List with Products and pass it to the ReportViewer. The problem is that it shows only the one product, it's the last in List. Where I wrong?

```
private void InvoiceForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ShopCartBindingSource.DataSource = list;

            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `list.Count`?

Comment: We do not know the content of `list`, we don't know the layout of the report and we do not know how the report gets its data. More info needed!

Comment: The content of list has "ShopCart"class with string and double properties. For the Report I have used Report Wizard, "Data source type" is Object. At "Dataset Properties" I have set "ShopCart". After all in WIndows form I added a ReportViewer and selected current project from Wizard. That is all I had done.

Comment: I found where the problem is. In a specific condition with If clause, my code doesn't add an object to list. Thank you guys!